# Creating a generic linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

Having some trouble with linked lists in C.

To create a linked list I would consider the following steps:

- create the node with the data type and a pointer do the next node;
- create the reference to the first node(head) or no node, `head == null`;

then create the functions which operate with the list.

My major trouble is `char` array and pointers.  I would just love a generic linked list.  The ones I searched for are far too complicated.

```
struct nodeCategoria {
  int ident;
  char design[MAX];
  struct nodeCategoria* next;
};

struct nodeCategoria* headCat;

void insereCat(){
  int ident1;
  char arr[MAX];
  struct nodeCategoria* novo;

  printf("Identificacao : ");
  scanf("%d", &ident1);
  printf("Designacao : ");
  novo->ident = ident1;
  novo->design = scanf("%c[^\n]");
}
```

Comment: Look what you're doing: creating a pointer to `struct nodeCategoria` but not making it point to anything. Where do you think the memory will come from? `novo->anything` _is not there_! You have to allocate memory with `malloc`

Answer (score 2):

I had a simmilar requirement for one of my projects, can came up with this:

- https://github.com/WayneBooth/opendias/blob/master/src/simpleLinkedList.c
- https://github.com/WayneBooth/opendias/blob/master/src/simpleLinkedList.h

Example use:

```
struct simpleLinkedList *vars = sll_init();
sll_append(vars, someData);
sll_append(vars, otherData);

vars = sll_findFirstElement(vars);
char *myData1 = vars->data;
vars = sll_getNext(vars);
char *myData2 = vars->data;

sll_destroy(vars);
```

It has a few extra methods on it (sorting, etc...) which you can just ignore. Maybe this will be useful for you.

Comment: Also check https://github.com/ucodev/libpall . Maybe it'll be like shooting a mosquito with a rocket in this case, but it also implements a very simple interface. Check the example/ directory contents.